# Prove that $\Bbb R$ satisfies Nested Interval Property (NIP) implies it satisfies Axiom of Completeness (AoC) as well.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that  $\Bbb R$ satisfies Nested Interval Property (NIP) implies it satisfies Axiom of Completeness (AoC) as well.

I tried solving this problem hereby:

We consider $S\subset \mathbb R$ such that $S\neq\emptyset$ and $S$ is bounded above.

We need to show that, $\sup S$ exists in $\Bbb R.$

As $S$ is bounded then, $\exists M\in\Bbb R$ such that $s\leq M$ $,\forall s\in S.$ We assume, $\exists s_0\in S$ as $S$ is nonempty and $m_0=M.$ We now bustect the interval $I_0=[s_0,M_0]$ at $\frac{s_0+m_0}{2}$. We write, $s_1=\frac{s_0+m_0}{2}$ if $\frac{s_0+m_0}{2}\in S$ and $m_1=m_0.$ If $\frac{s_0+m_0}{2}\notin S$ we write, $m_1=\frac{s_0+m_0}{2}$ and $s_1=s_0.$

In either cases, we note that, $I_1=[s_1,m_1]\subset I_0$ and $$|I_1|=m_1-s_1\leq \frac{1}{2}(m_0-s_0)=|I_0|.$$ We again bisect $I_1$ and continue this process to obtain a sequence of closed intervals $I_n,n\in\Bbb N\cup \{0\}=N'.$

By NIP, we have, $\exists$ a unique $c\in \cap I_n.$ We claim, $\sup S=c.$

If $s\in S$ and $\exists n\in N'$ such that $s\leq s_n$ then, $s\leq s_n\leq c.$

*If $s\gt s_n,\forall n'\in N',$ then, $s_n\leq s\leq m_n,\forall n\in N'\implies c=s,$ as $c$ is unique by NIP.*

Thus, $c$ is an upper bound of $S.$

If, $\exists M'\in\Bbb R$ such that $s\leq M'$ we claim, $c\leq M'.$ For if, $c\gt M'\geq s,\forall s\in S$ then, $$s_n\leq M'\lt c\leq m_n\implies M'\in \cap I_n\implies c=M',$$ a contradiction. So, $c\leq M'\implies c=\sup S.$

This completes the proof.

---

However, I still have some doubts regarding my solution. This is because, I am doubtful with the statement :

> *If $s\gt s_n,\forall n'\in N',$ then, $s_n\leq s\leq m_n,\forall n\in N'\implies c=s,$ as $c$ is unique by NIP.*

in the above solution. For it may, happen that $\exists n\in N'$ such that $s\gt m_n$ if ($m_n\notin S$ by definition of $m_i's$ and,) $m_n$ is not an upper bound of $S.$ I think this is the point where the logic of my proof breaks down or rather becomes awry.

I want to know if this is an issue then how can we fix this? Else, if that statement above is correct, then how is that justified ?

Comment: Indeed, a problem occurs with your recursive bisection if $S$ is not connected. Let $S= (0,2)\cup(3,4)$. Choosing $s_0=1$ and $M=4$ gives $s_1=1$ and $m_1=2.5$, which will converge to $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the above post has issues for the same reasons as mentioned in the OP, i.e the $m_n$ might not be an upper bound of $S.$ The $m_n's$ are such that, $m_n\notin S$ but it is not absolutely mandatory, that the $m_n'$ have to be an upper bound of $S.$ In other words, it is entirely possible, for an $s\in S$ such that $s\gt m_n$ for some $n.$ We can never gurantee that $s\leq m_n$ for all $s\in S.$ In that case, $c$ fails to be even an upper bound of $S$ let alone, the least upper bound.

However, the proof in the original post can be fixed with a modification, by which we are constructing the nested sequence of closed intervals. Here it is:

We consider $s_0\in S,$ and $M\in \Bbb R,$ such that $M$ is an upper bound for $S.$

Then, we bisect $I_0=[s_0,M]$ at $\frac{s_0+M_0}{2}$. If, $\frac{s_0+M_0}{2}$ is an upper bound of $S$ we assume, $M_1=\frac{s_0+M_0}{2}$ and $s_1=s_0.$ If, $\frac{s_0+M_0}{2}$ is not an upper bound for $S$ then, $\exists s\in S$ such that $\frac{s_0+M_0}{2}\lt s'.$ In this case, we let $s_1=s'$ and $M_1=M_0.$ We hence,  consider the interval, $I_1=[s_1,M_1].$

We note, that $|I_1|=|M_1-s_1|\leq\frac 12|M_0-s_0|=|I_0|.$ Also, $I_1\subset I_0.$

We again, bisect $I_1$ and repeat the same process to obtain a sequence of nested closed intervals $I_1\supset I_2\supset I_3\cdots.$

And if $I_n$ is a closed interval from the above sequence, then $|I_n|\leq (\frac 12)^n|I_{0}|\implies \lim|I_n|=0.$

---

With this construction, the proof becomes easy , as follows:

Applying NIP, we can assert that $\exists$ a unique $c\in\cap I_n.$ Now, we claim : $sup S=c.$

We note that, if  $s\in S$ be an arbitrary element,  such that $\exists n_0\in \Bbb N\cup \{0\}$ , $s\leq s_{n_0}$ then, $s\leq s_{n_0}\leq c.$ This is because, $s_n\leq c\leq M_n$, for every non-negative integer $n$ [By NIP].

If $s\in S$ such that, $s\geq s_n$ for every non-negative integer $n,$ then, we have $s_n\leq s\leq M_n,$ *as each $M_n$ is an upper bound of $S.$*

Now, as $c$ is unique so, $s=c,$ (again a conclusion from NIP).

Thu, in all cases we have, $s\leq c$ for all $s\in S.$

Till now, we have proved $c$ as an upper bound of $S.$

Indeed $c$ is the least upper bound of $S$, for if $M'$ is an arbitrary upper bound of $S$ then, if $c\leq M$ then, we are done. If $c\gt M'$, then we have, $s_n\leq M'\lt c\leq M_n$ for each non-negative integer $n.$ From, NIP, we then have, $c=M',$ a contradiction. So, $c\leq M'.$

---

This proof is probably fixed in this way. If there are any errors please, do let me know.